# Qt memory managment for QML elements

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, qt4, qml

I have a simple Qt application using QML elements, once i start the application it takes around 40Mb, now I create dynamically object for single page.

Example.

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("AboutUs.qml");
 var object = component.createObject(mainPage);
```

and destroy them when i close the page using
  object.destroy()

The behavior of application is strange : As whenever a simple object it created it takes around 1Mb, but when i delete the object, them memory is not deallocation.

Now my application has 20 pages of this kind, So if i open each page single time the total memory occupied by application is around 60Mb, which is like memory leak.

I am not able to find out why it is happening, is it the javascriptengine occupying the memory and not releasing it, or it is java script local variables,that are not releasing memory, or it is QT4, which is caching to create objects.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Qt's site :

> Items can be deleted using the destroy() method. This method has an
>   optional argument (which defaults to 0) that specifies the approximate
>   delay in milliseconds before the object is to be destroyed.
>
> Objects are not destroyed the instant destroy() is called, but are
>   cleaned up sometime between the end of that script block and the next
>   frame (unless you specified a non-zero delay).

You should try calling `destroy()` with a parameter to make it delete the object immediately.